# How can i check edit text's content using espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have few buttons that type in an edit text and i'm trying to write a test in espresso which verifies if a certain text gets to the edit text, any idea how to?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should perform a click on the button you are talking about and then assert it with the value of your `EditText`:

```
onView(withId(R.id.myButton)).perform(click());
onView(withId(R.id.editText)).check(matches(withText("Text you wish to match")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check EditText value like this :-

> Click of your button -> Get EditText's value and match it with your
>   content.

```
onView(withId(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID)).perform(click())
onView(withId(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID)).check(matches(withHint("your_content")))
```

Comment: @panduru-ionut check this